# FullCalendar and path to web service for Events

Tags: vb.net, web-services, url, relative-path

I'm using FullCalendar in my project, and would like to pull Event objects from a web service written in VB .Net.  My web service code sits in the /App_Code/ folder.  The web page which uses FullCalendar sits in the /Admin/MaintainTimeboxes/ folder.  How do i specify to FullCalendar the path to the web service?

The code I'm using to put FullCalendar on the page is:

```
var initializeCalendar = function () {
$('.calendar').fullCalendar({
editable: true,
eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
events: "TestService.vb/GetEventList",
defaultTimedEventDuration: '00:30:00',
forceEventDuration: true,
eventBackgroundColor: '#337ab7',
//editable: false,
height: screen.height - 160,
timezone: 'America/Chicago',
eventStartEditable: false,
eventDurationEditable: false
});
};
```

The error I get in my browser is:

```
HTTP404: NOT FOUND - The server has not found anything matching the requested URI (Uniform Resource Identifier).
(XHR)GET - http://localhost:64805/Admin/MaintainTimeboxes/TestService.vb/GetEventList?start=2018-02-25&end=2018-04-08&timezone=America%2FChicago&_=1520713835205
```

You can see that it's assuming my web service sits in the same folder as the page containing FullCalendar (/Admin/MaintainTimeboxes/), but the web service has to sit in the App_Code folder.

Any assistance would be much appreciated.

Comment: I would think it would be `../../App_Code/TestService.vb/GetEventList` but it might depend on exactly how your app is set up. This is really nothing to do with fullCalendar, or even VB and is basically a question about relative URLs

Comment: That worked, thanks!  I didn't even think of using Javascript relative URL's - I had tried .Net relative URLs.  Now I have a different problem in that it tells me that the URI cannot be found although the path is correct.  The message I get is: HTTP404: NOT FOUND - The server has not found anything matching the requested URI (Uniform Resource Identifier).
(XHR)GET - http://localhost:64805/App_Code/TestService.vb/GetEventList?start=2018-02-25&end=2018-04-08&timezone=America%2FChicago&_=1520881721489

Comment: If it still returns a 404 then clearly the URI is still not correct. That's what a 404 error means.